# SEO Title Tag and Meta Description for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, seo, hierarchical

I have hierarchical taxonomy called "Location" e.g. mywebsite.com/location/state/city
I want  mywebsite.com/location/state and mywebsite.com/location/state/city to have different title tag I want them to be ...

mywebsite.com/location/state = Welcome to "state" location

mywebsite.com/location/state/city = Welcome to "state", "city" location

Same thing for meta descriptions. I tried configuring header.php but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I assume location/state and location/state/city are template files. In those 2 template files you should copy the contents of header.php and edit there the title and the meta description. Also delete the request `get_header()`.